# Не понятное мне поведение Javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть простейший к примеру код:

```
if(a > 1)
   if(a > 2) ..todo;

else ..nothing;
```

Если a > 1 но оказывается не больше 2 то происходит действия в else.

Почему так? Ведь else относится к false самой первой проверки а не её внутренней? Если я внесу выражение в фигурные скобки:

```
if(a > 1){
   if(a > 2) ..todo;
}

else ..nothing;
```

То при a больше 1 но не больше 2 else не сработает. Разве по логике без скобок не должно быть тоже самое? Это ведь просто сокращение а не направление внутреннего if к внешнему else даже если оно следует далее в коде.

Comment: Самый лучший вариант всегда и везде ставить скобки. Во первых не будит таких ошибок а во вторых более читабельным будет код.

Answer (score 6):

> Ведь else относится к false самой первой проверки

Нет.

В яваскрипте отступы не играют роли. Поэтому `else` относится к ближайшему `if`.

Т.е данный код

```
if(a > 1)
   if(a > 2) ..todo;

else ..nothing;
```

На самом деле является таким:

```
if(a > 1){
    if(a > 2) {
        ..todo;
    }
    else {
        ..nothing;
    }
}
```